# Database issue (orphaned migrations) when using git flow branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, schema, git-flow

Have a git flow question if anyone can help. I'm not really comfortable with using the git flow approach to things so this may be a very stupid question, but here goes:

The way my company handles things is by naming each feature after a specific issue code that relates to the GitHub "issues" page. So, for example, I finished `feature/issue-3118` a short time ago. In that branch, I had to remove 2 columns from the user table and clear out (or change) anything that was trying to access it. This was completed, all tests passed etc so I pushed the branch. I then did a `git checkout develop` and started  a new feature branch for the next task assigned to me (called `feature/issue-3201`).

The problem I have now is that the current branch is failing a bunch of tests that were fixed in the last branch. Running `rake db:migrate:status` shows my 2 previous migrations as now being orphaned so methods etc. trying to access them are failing tests.

The `issue-3118` branch is still in review so I can not just update my master and be on my way. Rather than going through all the database changes again manually (or waiting for the master to be updated), is there an easy way to get over this issue? If I merge the branches, won't this cause conflict issues when I push the current branch?

(If this does indeed sound like a really stupid question, I am about as junior as junior devs get - started my first web development job on August 1st!)

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with ruby on rails so I'm not entirely sure of best practice regarding database testing/migration. Do the changes in your current branch depend on the changes you made in your `feature/issue-3318` branch? Have you started this new feature branch from `master`? If not, are the tests in your `master` branch failing as well?

Comment: Yeah, the second feature is dependent on the first being completed - that was why the RSPEC tests were having trouble since they were set correctly before the changes were made.

Comment: Ah ok. Looks like the answer has you covered, good luck =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, which is likely the way that I would do it, is to start the new feature branch from your `feature/issue-3118` branch, rather than from the head of `develop`.  This is not the standard approach, but it sounds as though your new feature is dependent on the completion of `feature/issue-3118`.

That way, the new feature, will already have those changes in it, and you can continue work there.

Then, once `feature/issue-3118` is merged into develop, you can rebase your new feature branch on `develop`, and continue work.

This maintains the segregation of the work that needs to happen, but allows you to continue while `issue-3118` is being reviewed.

Likely, you should get sign off from other people in your team prior to going down this route.

Comment: Decided to ask the lead dev as you suggested, he echoed your ideas so I have my answer now - thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working! Hope it all goes well :-D